# Is it possible to use await on part of a line?

Tags: javascript, async-await

This may be a dumb question but I can't quite get my head around it.

Say I have the following, where `got(url)` returns a promise:

```
let json = await got(url).json();
```

I think that won't work, because it will try to call `.json()` immediately and then try to `await` the result of the `.json()` call. I could fix it by doing this:

```
let response = await got(url);
let json = response.json();
```

But that's a little gross IMO. Is there a way to `await` only the first part of the line (i.e. the `got(url)` part) and then continue with the rest of the line (i.e. the `.json()` part) after the first part completes?

Comment: Assuming [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) also returns a promise... `let json = await (await got(url)).json()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
let json = (await got(url)).json();
```

Comment: Aha, awesome! As it turns out, I was using `Got` wrong and didn't need this at all, but this is still extremely useful to know, so thanks!